# Apply DomSanitizationService in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, captcha, unsafe, sanitize

Currently I have to support an Angular project.

There is an security issue report on unsafe image, the error message show under Chrome console is as follow:

```
unsafe:data:image/png;base64,:1 GET unsafe:data:image/png;base64, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

I google around, and found that I need to use DomSanitizationService to sanitize the value. However, I keep having problem when code on it, I suspect is syntax error. The following is my HTML code:

```html
<img src="{{ _DomSanitizationService.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(captchaSrc) }}"  height="auto" width="100%" id="captcha-img" />
```

And the following is my TypeScript file code:

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

captchaSrc: string = 'data:image/png;base64,';

constructor(
    public _DomSanitizationService: DomSanitizer
  ) {
  }

this.captchaSrc += this.captcha.captchaImg;
```

I am having the following error in chrome console:

```
unsafe:SafeValue must use [property]=binding: data:image/png;base64, (see http://g.co/ng/security net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

Any ideas on what mistake I make?

***** Edit *****
After I refer Adrita Sharma answer, I still have some issue, which is I by pass in method, but it does not take effect:

```
startRegistration(via: string): void {
     this.sharedService.generateCaptcha().subscribe(response => {
     this.captcha = response;
     this.captchaSrc += this.captcha.captchaImg;
     this._DomSanitizationService.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.captchaSrc);
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you follow and read the suggested link? The message seems clear - you need to use property binding with `[]`, not interpolation with `{{}}`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe , ya, I actually tried, but still having syntax error, because I am new to angular, and I use like this `[src]={captchaSrc}`, now I change to use the following answer one, which is `[src]="captchaSrc"`, but I still having chrome error unsafe:data.

Comment: So give a [mcve] of that - how are you using the DomSanitizer in that context? `[src]={captchaSrc}` is clearly invalid syntax in the template, so show how you're working with `[src]="captchaSrc"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
constructor( public _DomSanitizationService: DomSanitizer) {
   _DomSanitizationService.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.captchaSrc)
}
```

Template:

```
<img [src]="captchaSrc" height="auto" width="100%" id="captcha-img" />
```

EDIT:

```
yourMethod(){
    this.captchaSrc = this._DomSanitizationService.bypassSecurityTrustUrl('data:image/png;base64,' + this.captchaSrc)
}
```

Comment: Hi @Adrita Sharma, after apply your changes, I not longer hit `unsafe:SafeValue must use [property]=binding:`, however, I have another question, because I still need to append the `captchaImg` after the 'data:image/png;base64,', thus I will still hitting the unsafe error because the sanitize only happen in constructor, but the value I append is on method. I do try put the `this._DomSanitizationService.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.captchaSrc);` in method, but looks like it didnt take effect.

Comment: You can append it in TS before bypassing

Comment: Ya, I am append it in ts, I am append it in method, which is means, this method only run after constructor.

Comment: Show that method

Comment: Check the modified answer

Comment: I just add in the method. The method you provided under edit also not work for me as well, because my captchaSrc is a String.

Comment: The error will be `unsafe:data:image/png;base64,:1 GET unsafe:data:image/png;base64, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME` if I use `this._DomSanitizationService.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.captchaSrc);`. Cant apply `this.captchaSrc = this._DomSanitizationService.bypassSecurityTrustUrl('data:image/png;base64,' + this.captchaSrc)` because it will have compilation error, because captchaSrc is a String.

Comment: I found it, I do it in html instead of ts, `<img [src]="_DomSanitizationService.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(captchaSrc)"  height="auto" width="100%" id="captcha-img" >`

Answer (score 0):

Try it
.ts

```
import { DomSanitizer, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';
export class TESTComponent {
  _imageUrlNotSanitized: SafeUrl;
  image: string;
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
  ngOnInit() {
      this._imageUrlNotSanitized = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.image);
}
}
```

.html
`<img [src]="_imageUrlNotSanitized">`

Comment: Hi @shuts13, not sure why I am getting `null:1 GET http://localhost:4200/null 404 (Not Found)` at the html `<img [src]="_imageUrlNotSanitized">`